# Using List as Radio Group

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using a UL as a radio group and the following script to:

1. Add/remove a class on the li (basically the active state).
2. Set the value of the li as the value in a corresponding text field.

**Script:**

```
jQuery(function($){
    var hinput = $('input[name="range1"]');
    $("ul#range1 li").click( function() {

    hinput.val($(this).attr('value'))
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    });
})
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="rangeSelect" id="range1">
     <li value="1"><span>1</span></li>
     <li value="2"><span>2</span></li>
     <li value="3"><span>3</span></li>
</ul>
<input type="text" name="range1">
```

This set up works fine for one group, however doesn't allow for multiple groups on a single page.

I'm struggling to modify the script to allow:

1. The input name (in the script) to be set to the ID on the parent UL.
2. The UL ID (in the script) to be set to the ID on the parent UL.
3. Apply the active class to the li within the active list (rather than only one active state activating across multiple ULs).

All of these points are designed to allow more than one list to be used without modifying/duplicating the script.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EjNyT/1/

Thanks in advance.

@rrfive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal suggestion would be to create a simple plug-in that can work with multiple elements, for example:

```
// creating a jQuery plug-in, protecting the '$' alias:
(function ($) {
    // defining the name of the plug-in itself, and supplying 'opts' to make it,
    // in some small way, customisable:
    $.fn.listRadio = function (opts) {
        // incorporating the user-defined options (from 'opts') with
        // the defined defaults (those defined in the object literal):
        var settings = $.extend({
            'activeClassName' : 'active',
            'valueProperty' : 'data-value'
        }, opts);

        // 'this' is the jQuery object, not a DOM node, we're iterating over that:
        this.each(function () {
            // $(this) is the current element in the collection over
            // which we're iterating:
            var wrapper = $(this),

                // defining which element should receive the value,
                // in this case it's the 'input' whose 'name' is equal
                // to the current-element's id property:
                outputTo = $('input[name="' + wrapper.prop('id') + '"]');

            // binding a click-handler to the current element:
            wrapper.on('click', function (e) {

                // caching the clicked element:
                var target = e.target,
                    $self;

                // finding out which element should receive the active state,
                // if the clicked element is an 'li' that should be the active element:
                if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li') {
                    $self = $(target);
                }

                // otherwise, it should be the element that has the activeClassName:
                else if (wrapper.find('li.' + settings.activeClassName).length) {
                    $self = wrapper.find('li.' + settings.activeClassName);
                }

                // otherwise it's the first 'li' in the current element
                // (this will likely be the case only on page-load):
                else {
                    $self = wrapper.find('li').eq(0);
                }

                // setting the value to the relevant property/attribute of
                // whichever element is currently 'active':
                outputTo.val($self.attr(settings.valueProperty));

                $self

                    // adding the activeClassName to the 'active' element:
                    .addClass(settings.activeClassName)

                    // finding the siblings of the active element:
                    .siblings()

                    // removing the activeClassName from those siblings:
                    .removeClass(settings.activeClassName);
            // triggering the click-event, so the plugin acts on page-load:
            }).click();
        });
    };
}(jQuery));

// call like so (no customisation):
$('.rangeSelect').listRadio();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EjNyT/3/).

```
// call and set a different class-name to represent the 'active' state:
$('.rangeSelect').listRadio({
    'activeClassName' : 'otherClassName'
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EjNyT/4/).

In the above note that there is still an `li` element with the `active` class-name, which still colours it red but doesn't affect the selection of the other `li` elements.

```
// call and set a different attribute from which to receive the 'value':
$('.rangeSelect').listRadio({
    'valueProperty' : 'id'
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EjNyT/5/).

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
  - [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).
- 'Plain' JavaScript:

  - [`Element.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.tagName).
  - [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
- Resources:

  - "[How to Create a Basic Plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)."

Comment: David, thank you. This solution is perfect and taught be a lot!

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! :)